# How can i add multi lines together into different different div / span tag through this text box?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can i add multi lines together into different different span tag through this text box ?

There is an text box, by using this box i can insert a new div / span class content Right ?
But every time when i need to add new class i need to write a new line in this text box and need to press send button, Now i want that if i have 10 lines content together with "Enter" button line break

Like 
My Line 1 is here 
My Line 2 is here 
My Line 3 is here
My Line 4 is here
My Line 5 is here
My Line 6 is here
My Line 7 is here
My Line 8 is here
... and so on

then i want to paste all 10 lines in this text box together and by pressing send button i want that all lines must be add in different different div / span class not all in one class with < br > tag that is working now.

so plz help me to improve my code
Love you Helper and Thanks in Advance

```js
const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-btn');
const textArea = document.getElementById('input');
const innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner');
var message = textArea.value;

sendButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const message = new MessageContainerBuilder().BuildMessage(textArea.value);
    innerDiv.appendChild(message);
    textArea.value = '';
});

function encodeHtmlEntity(input) {
    var output = input.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function (i) {
        return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    });

    return output;
}

function MessageContainerBuilder() {
    var createDivElement = function (classTest) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');

        var classAttr = document.createAttribute('class');
        classAttr.value = classTest;
        div.setAttributeNode(classAttr);

        return div;
    };

    var createSpanElement = function (value, classTest) {
        var span = document.createElement('span');

        if (classTest) {
            var classAttr = document.createAttribute('class');
            classAttr.value = classTest;
            span.setAttributeNode(classAttr);
        }

        span.innerText = encodeHtmlEntity(value);

        return span;
    };

    this.BuildMessage = function (text) {
        var divContainer = createDivElement('outgoing');
        var messageSpan = createSpanElement(text, 'me');

        divContainer.appendChild(messageSpan);

        return divContainer;
    };
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">
    <div class="incoming">
        <div class="them">Lorem
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outgoing">
        <div class="me">Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

<textarea class="input" id="input" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
<button class="waves-effect waves-light" id="send-btn">Send</button>
```

so plz help me to improve my code
Love you Helper and Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some liberties and simplified your code as you can see below.  It does everything I believe your code was attempting.

Note that I'm using `.split("\n")` to break your input based on each newline character and then iterate over that as necessary.

Also, you said you were inserting a div/span, but I don't see your code actually creating a span tag.  I wrote my code to do that for you though.

```js
const sendButton = document.getElementById('send-btn');
const textArea = document.getElementById('input');
const innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner');
var message = textArea.value;

sendButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // split the textarea entries into an array
  let lines = (textArea.value).split("\n");

  // iterate over each line, creating a div/span and inserting into the DOM
  lines.forEach( (line) => {
    let encodedLine = encodeHtmlEntity(line);
    let newElement = `<div class="me"><span>${encodedLine}</span></div>`;
    innerDiv.innerHTML += newElement;
  });
  
  // reset the textarea
  textArea.value = '';

});

function encodeHtmlEntity(input) {
  var output = input.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
    return '&#' + i.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
  });

  return output;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">
  <div class="incoming">
    <div class="them">Lorem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outgoing">
    <div class="me">Lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<textarea class="input" id="input" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
<button class="waves-effect waves-light" id="send-btn">Send</button>
```

Comment: Thank You Marc for your valuable response, Love You

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) so that each text is separated by `\n` (new line) into an array, then you can iterate over each element like using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Here's the code you can use:

```
sendButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
  textArea.value.split('\n').forEach((text) => {
    const message = new MessageContainerBuilder().BuildMessage(text);
    innerDiv.appendChild(message);
  });
  textArea.value = '';
});
```